# Melpomene hat has contrast problems

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash-2015

The Melpomene hat is nearly invisible on some avatars and site designs because it lacks any outlining to prevent disappearing into white areas:

[image: Melpomene is nearly invisible on my white-blue avatar]

(It similarly disappears into its own hat box on the Winter Bash site itself.)

Giving it an outline like so would make it more visible regardless of background:

[image: Melpomene given a thin black stroke line]

Presumably the Thalia hat has the same thing going on.

Comment: It does. That said, I kind of like it, in a weird way.  It looks [awesomely creepy](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r2PfS.png) on my avatar. :)

Comment: The Thalia *does* have the same thing going on, but with a smile.

Comment: I like how it blends into Community's profile picture. That's the main reason I set this one as Community's hat on PPCG :P

Comment: Your face has contrast problems. (Sorry. I'm just [on edge today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270851/1438).)

Comment: Wonder if Freud (or Rorschach) could say anything _special_ about the picture. It sure looks strange.

Comment: @JonEricson Come to think, that could be a legit answer.

Comment: @JonEricson: Yes, but sometimes you don't have a choice of the face. On  http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/ or on the "Your Hats" dialog from my user page, hats shows up on a white background, not on a face. Further, hats can extend outside the avatar, and Most SE sites have a white background.  This bothered me in the Secret Hats thread where most people put screenshots of hats with such confusing backgrounds, which is why I made the edit http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/270793/3 where I rendered the hat on a blue background.  (The larger resolution is just a bonus.)